# A question about dahlquist's test equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The lecture notes about numerical methods for ODEs notes that for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and
$$
x'(t)=\lambda x(t)
$$
the solution is
$$
x(t)=x(t_0)\exp(\lambda(t-t_0))
$$
and (now the point that confueses me) this x(t) is bounded iff Re$(\lambda)\leq 0$. Why is that? And how can one show the last part?

\Edit: I had a wrong condition for Re$(\lambda)$. Sorry for that and thank you to Lutz.

Comment: Please check again, the condition should be that $Re(λ)$ zero or negative. Or that the exponential function if you replace $ λ$ with $Re(λ)$ is a bounded real function for $t\ge t_0$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann: You are absolutely correct, please excuse my stupid mistake. I edited the question.

Comment: Is it sufficient to note that $|e^z|=e^{Re(z)}$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann: Thanks, that allready helped I think with one of the ifs. If Re$(\lambda)\leq 0$, then $|x(t)|\leq |x(t_0)|$ since $|(e^\lambda)^{(t-t_0)}|\leq |1^{(t-t_0)}|$, is that correct? In the other direction I would guess that if the Re$(\lambda)$ would be bigger that 0, then $exp(\lambda)>1$ and that would mean that for $t \rightarrow \infty$ the $x(t)$ would go also go to $\infty$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Many thanks! Helped a lot.